# Linux. Как подсчитать количество строк содержащих заданную последовательность символов в заданном файле

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Как подсчитать количество строк содержащих заданную последовательность символов в заданном файле. Допустим есть файл в домашнем каталоге info.txt 
он содержит такие строки:

- linux good
- linux good
- linux best
- linux cool

Как узнать количество строк. Где встречается слово good ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Находим с помощью `grep` нужные строки и считаем их с помощью `wc`:

```
grep good info.txt | wc -l
```

Comment: Не первый год использую linux на домашнем ПК, но до сих пор не привык к тому, насколько просто решаются весьма специфические задачи.

Comment: @jumpjet67: `grep -c -w good info.txt`

Comment: @jfs уже слегка не UNIX-way - "программа решает только одну задачу, но делает это максимально эффективно.", хотя я не сторонник крайностей.

Comment: @jumpjet67  `-w` находит только *целые* слова (естественная часть `grep`, которую `wc -l` не реализует). Устоявшуюся функциональность полезно в программу включать, чтобы не реализовывать с нуля каждый раз, например это позволяет статус возврата установить, если `-c` ноль возвращает. Если редко приходится использовать `-c`, то конечно хорошо знать о `wc -l` так как её и с другими командами можно использовать. Другой пример: `sort -u` и `uniq`.

Answer (score 3):

Вот более кортокий вариант:

```
grep good info.txt -c
```